# How to remove spring boot permission to do database structural changes

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Spring boot application has the ability to do structural changes on the database such as creating and deleting tables, tables columns, primary keys etc.

Is there a way to remove the application permission to do that?

Would like the application to be allowed to do only the regular operations of select, insert, update and delete.

Any structural change on the db such as creating and deleting tables, should be done only directly in the database.

Is there anyway to do that?

Comment: Are you using hibernate with spring boot?

Comment: Not sure. How can I check? I didn't make any explicit configuration for it. In spring initializr I picked Spring Boot DevTools, Spring Web and Thymeleaf. On pom.xml no references to hibernate. I do have spring-boot-starter-data-jpa in there. But taking a look in the Maven Dependencies folder there are hibernate .jars listed. So seems that yes.

Comment: how are you connecting the application to database ? Are you using JPA repositories ? Please add your ```application.properties``` file

Comment: right. There is hibernate in there. This is how it is: spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dbname
spring.datasource.username=dbusername
spring.datasource.password=dbpass
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

Comment: in this ,change  ```spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update```  to ```spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none``` to stop updating the DB based on your Entity class.Detailed answer is given below as answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring provides a JPA-specific property which Hibernate uses for DDL generation: `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto`.

The standard Hibernate property values are: **create, update, create-drop, validate and none**

`create` – Hibernate first drops existing tables, then creates new tables

`update` – the object model created based on the mappings (annotations or XML) is compared with the existing schema, and then Hibernate updates the schema according to the diff. It never deletes the existing tables or columns even if they are no more required by the application

`create-drop` – similar to create, with the addition that Hibernate will drop the database after all operations are completed. Typically used for unit testing

`validate` – Hibernate only validates whether the tables and columns exist, otherwise it throws an exception

`none` – this value effectively turns off the DDL generation

In your case , you have to change the property  `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` to `none` in your `application.properties` file to stop spring boot from automatically updating your DB schemas.

Hope this helps  . For more info https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.1.0.M1/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html

Comment: Yes, this worked. Thanks for the detailed explanation. Answer accepted.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add this in application.properties

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = none
```

Hope useful

Comment: Yes, this worked. Thanks. Could mark this as accepted as well but already did that on the other answer that provided the same information. So I'm upvoting this one also. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

First, if using Hibernate, then, set the `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` property to `none`

Second, if your app shouldn't be able to execute DDL commands on your DB, then just revoke the permissions from the application's user directly into the database.

Comment: Yes, this worked. Thank you. Could mark this as accepted but already did that on the other answer that provided the same information. So I'm upvoting this one. Thank you.